# How can I use TypeProviders to work with MS Access

Tags: f#

From one side I cannot use:

```
type dbSchema = OleDbConnection<"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\\\Sources\\Experiments\\DbAccess\db.accdb">
```

On the other side:

```
let conn = OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\\\Sources\\Experiments\\DbAccess\db.accdb");
```

I can not get data context (GetDataContext()) from OleDbConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the SQLProvider type provider to get access to the MS Access database? There is a test script on the project's GitHub repository using it [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/master/tests/SqlProvider.Tests/MSAccessTests.fsx).

Comment: It doesn't have CRUD operations.  Only select query.